# Custom Formatting Double

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`.

I set all columns of the `DataTable` to `System.Double`.

I want the last row of the `DataGridView` to display `"PASS"` or `"FAIL"` depending on some *condition* of the values in that column.

How do I do this?

Ideas: 
`lastCell = IIF(condition, Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.NegativeInfinity)`
Then, apply some conditional formatting `(Inf -> PASS, -Inf -> FAIL)` to the final row of the DataGridView.

Comment: How are you defining "last row" is it a row in your datatable?  Or is it an additional row you want to create?  The datagridview doesn't have ideas like "last row" because it needs to deal with sorting, etc. where last row changes over time

Comment: By "last row", I mean the bottom row in the DataGridView which I want to simply display PASS / FAIL based on the values in that column.  As described by Joe, I added a DataGridView CellFormatting event handler which checked the column and displayed PASS/FAIL accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* probably create and use a custom `NumberFormatInfo`, setting `PositiveInfinitySymbol` and `NegativeInfinitySymbol` to the strings you want.

But I'd say it would be better to do something like this in the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event handler - which makes it much clearer what you're doing and why, and won't have undesirable side effects e.g. if another cell happens to have an infinite value because of a division by zero.

Something like the following air code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == whatever) && (c.RowIndex == whatever))
    {
        // ... comment explaining what you're doing
        if (condition)
        {
            e.Value = "PASS";
        }
        else
        {
           e.Value = "FAIL";
        }
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Apologies for the C# code given you've tagged the question VB.NET, but you'll find a VB.NET sample in the MDSN documentation for the CellFormatting event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an extra column to the table of type boolean?  Booleans are more appropriate here, since you have one of two states, it either passes (true), or doesn't pass (fail).

You can add the extra [DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx) and populate the values manually, or you can use a [computed DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx) and then bind the list to that having a "PASS" column on your DataGridView.

Comment: The PASS/FAIL applies to the values of that column.  It would make more sense to have it be the last row.  Also, transposing the grid (to make the status collection a column instead of row) would not make sense in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Build your condition in such a way that it evaluates to >= 0 for "PASS" or < 0 for "FAIL", and apply it before binding to the grid (perhaps in the query itself).  Then use this format string on the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property for the column in the grid:

> {0:"PASS";"FAIL";}